# Reading keys in plist and get the values

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following plist file in my Swift iOS project. I want to read the keys without specifically mention and get the value for all the keys. I want to write this in Swift code. I tried the below code and getting all the keys and values. But, I want to check for each key(not mentioned specifically like "1234" etc.) and get the value for it. Please help how to achieve this?

```
var myDict: NSDictionary?
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("UserDetails", ofType: "plist") {
      myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
      NSLog("myDict: %@", myDict!)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this code

```
for (key, val) in myDict! {
  println("\(key):\(val)")
}
```

to print the single keys/values.

Comment: Thank you. How do I NSLog of key and value there? or How Do I get value in string for a specific key?

Comment: `key` is already a `String`. You may cast `val` like `let s = val as String`. Also you can use `NSLog` instead of `print`

Comment: Please donate it to @ericd since he was a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tuple to loop in a dictionary:

```
for (key, value) in myDict! {
    println("Key is \(key) and value is \(value)")
}
```

Comment: Got it a few minutes too late ;-) You forgot the ! after myDict

Comment: Added the ! to conform to OP's example. Thanks. :)